# WTSEnumerateSessions from JNA

Tags: winapi, jna

I'm trying to start a UI application from a java based Windows Service. If figured out so far, that the only approach to make this work is to get a list of sessions, find the one thats currently active, get the user handle for that session and finally create a new process for the given user.

I'm starting off by implementing the session enumeration using [WTSEnumerateSessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), yet I'm struggling to get this working. The problem seems to be my mapping of the "_Out_ PWTS_SESSION_INFO *ppSessionInfo" parameter. I wrote the following code:

```
public interface Wtsapi32 extends StdCallLibrary {
   Wtsapi32 INSTANCE = (Wtsapi32) Native.loadLibrary("Wtsapi32", Wtsapi32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
   boolean WTSEnumerateSessions(IntByReference hServer, int Reserved, int Version, WTS_SESSION_INFO.ByReference[] ppSessionInfo, IntByReference pCount) throws LastErrorException;

   class WTS_SESSION_INFO extends Structure {
       public static class ByReference extends WTS_SESSION_INFO implements Structure.ByReference {}
       public int sessionId;
       public String pWinStationName;
       public int state;

       @Override
       protected List getFieldOrder() {
           return Arrays.asList("sessionId", "pWinStationName", "state");
       }
   }

}
```

On trying invoking the code with something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Wtsapi32.WTS_SESSION_INFO.ByReference[] sessionInfo = null;
        IntByReference sessionCount = new IntByReference();
        try {
            if (Wtsapi32.INSTANCE.WTSEnumerateSessions(new IntByReference(0), 0, 1, sessionInfo, sessionCount)) {
                System.out.println("success :-)");
            }
        } catch (LastErrorException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I get a error code 1784 - ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER. What would be the correct mapping for said API call from JNA?

**Update:**
I have tried a version suggested Remy Lebeau, but this gives me an Invalid memory access exception:

```
public interface Wtsapi32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    Wtsapi32 INSTANCE = (Wtsapi32) Native.loadLibrary("Wtsapi32", Wtsapi32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    boolean WTSEnumerateSessions(IntByReference hServer, int Reserved, int Version, PointerByReference ppSessionInfo, IntByReference pCount) throws LastErrorException;

    class WTS_SESSION_INFO extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends WTS_SESSION_INFO implements Structure.ByReference {}

        public int sessionId;
        public String pWinStationName;
        public int state;

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("sessionId", "pWinStationName", "state");
        }

        public WTS_SESSION_INFO() {}
        public WTS_SESSION_INFO(Pointer p) {
            super(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
    PointerByReference sessionInfoPtr = new PointerByReference();
    IntByReference sessionCount = new IntByReference();
    try {
        if (Wtsapi32.INSTANCE.WTSEnumerateSessions(new IntByReference(0), 0, 1, sessionInfoPtr, sessionCount)) {
            System.out.println("success :-)");
        }
    } catch (LastErrorException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The output of `WTSEnumerateSessions()` is a pointer to an array of structures. So you need to pass a reference to such a pointer, then you can use the pointer to access the array. [JNA Example #7: Retrieve an Array of Structs from C](http://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/example07.html)

Comment: I tried your approach, but this leads to an Invalid Memory Exception, see my updated question for the code I've tried.

Comment: Why are you using an `IntByReference` for the first parameter? It should be a [`com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE`](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinNT.HANDLE.html) instead, or at least a `Pointer`. In C, Win32 `HANDLE`s are basically just `void*` pointers. Either way, you need to set the first parameter to `Pointer.NULL` (which is what `WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE` is defined as) to enumerate the session of the local server.  `IntByReference(0)` is not the same thing.

Comment: You're a genius! I had the IntByReference because the C# sample code I have used an IntPtr 0 and that seemed to be the right choice! Do you want to answer the question and I accept it or should I answer it myself?

Comment: `IntPtr(0)` in C# is equivalent to `Pointer.NULL` in JNA, not to `IntByReference(0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WTSEnumerateSessions()` returns:

- a ***pointer*** to an array of `WTS_SESSION_INFO` structures
- a ***pointer*** to a `DWORD` of the number of elements in the the array.

So you need to pass a `PointerByReference` for the `ppSessionInfo` parameter, and a `IntByReference` for the `pCount` parameters.  You can then use the values being pointed at by those pointers to access the array elements as needed.  There is an example of this documented here:

[JNA Example #7: Retrieve an Array of Structs from C](http://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/example07.html)

Also, your code is using an `IntByReference` for the `hServer` parameter. It needs to be a [`com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE`](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/WinNT.HANDLE.html) instead, or at least a `Pointer`. In C, a Win32 `HANDLE` is just a `void*` pointer. You need to set the first parameter to `Pointer.NULL` (which is what `WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE` is defined as in C) to enumerate the sessions of the local server. `IntByReference(0)` is not the same thing as `Pointer.NULL`.

And don't forget to call `WTSFreeMemory()` to free the array data when you are done using it.

Try something like this:

```
public interface Wtsapi32 extends StdCallLibrary {
   Wtsapi32 INSTANCE = (Wtsapi32) Native.loadLibrary("Wtsapi32", Wtsapi32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

   boolean WTSEnumerateSessions(Pointer hServer, int Reserved, int Version, PointerByReference ppSessionInfo, IntByReference pCount) throws LastErrorException;
   void WTSFreeMemory(Pointer pMemory);

   class WTS_SESSION_INFO extends Structure {
       public static class ByReference extends WTS_SESSION_INFO implements Structure.ByReference {}

       public int sessionId;
       public String pWinStationName;
       public int state;

       public WTS_SESSION_INFO() {}
       public WTS_SESSION_INFO(Pointer p) {
           super(p);
       }

       @Override
       protected List getFieldOrder() {
           return Arrays.asList("sessionId", "pWinStationName", "state");
       }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    PointerByReference sessionInfoPtr = new PointerByReference();
    IntByReference sessionCount = new IntByReference();
    try {
        if (Wtsapi32.INSTANCE.WTSEnumerateSessions(Pointer.NULL, 0, 1, sessionInfoPtr, sessionCount)) {
            Pointer sessionInfo = sessionInfoPtr.getValue();
            int count = sessionCount.getValue();
            Wtsapi32.INSTANCE.WTS_SESSION_INFO arrRef = new Wtsapi32.INSTANCE.WTS_SESSION_INFO(sessionInfo);
            arrRef.read(); // <-- not sure why this is here
            Wtsapi32.INSTANCE.WTS_SESSION_INFO[] sessions = (Wtsapi32.INSTANCE.WTS_SESSION_INFO[])arrRef.toArray(count);
            for (Wtsapi32.INSTANCE.WTS_SESSION_INFO session : sessions) {
                // use session as needed...
            }
            WTSFreeMemory(sessionInfo);
        }
    } catch (LastErrorException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
```